# Dynamic Columns Alignment issue in RDLC report

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I have a RDLC report that has dynamic column (No. of columns changes with respect to parameters).So the width of Tablix is not static.I want to center align the tablix but as no. of column increases the alignment of tablix got disturbed.

Comment: Center align the tablix with respect to what? Page?

Comment: yes Page @Anup Agrawal

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately dynamic positioning is not possible in SSRS.  For example you cannot set the Location of a tablix to be cm.

I assume you are setting the visibility of various columns to show and hide them based on a parameter or calculation.  What you could do is to insert a blank column to the left of you tablix with a width half of the data column you want, and with a visibility set to the opposite of the data column.

For example

[image]

(Note the grey rows are for information only)